# Removing max in max heap java

Tags: java, max, heap

I am working on max heaps. I am able to add in the information, but when I remove the max something goes wrong. It switches numbers with 13's. Not sure why. Can someone look at my code and find where it isn't working?

It prints: `Heap  55 46 23 13 45 22 17 13 16 1 12`

When it should print: `Heap = 55 46 23 44 45 22 17 13 16 1 12`

Thank you!

```java
private int current; //Current number of nodes in heap
private int[]cu;  //Array to hold heap

public static final int maxSize =20;

public Heap ()
{
    cu= new int[maxSize];
    current = length();
}

private int length()
{
    for(int i=1; i<maxSize;i++)
    {
        if(cu[i]!=0)
            current++;
    }
    return current;
}

public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return (current ==1);
}

public boolean isFull()
{
    return (current == maxSize);
}


public boolean add(Comparable newNode)
{
    if(isFull())
        return false;

    current++;

    int t = current;
    int to;

    while(t>1)
    {
        to =t/2;
        if((int)newNode <= cu[to])
            break;
        else
        cu[t] = cu[to];
        t =to;
    }
    cu[t]= (int) newNode;
    return true;
}

public Comparable remove()
{   
    if(isEmpty())
        return false;

    int t= 1;
    int to=2;

    while(t<=current)
    {
        if((t<current)&& (cu[t]<=cu[t+1])) 
            t++;

         if(cu[t]<= cu[current])
            break;

        to=t;
         t*=2;
        cu[to] = cu[t];
    }
    if (current>1)
        cu[to] = cu[current];
    current--;
    return true;
}

public void print()
{
    System.out.print("\nHeap = ");
    for (int i = 1; i <= current; i++)
        System.out.print(cu[i] +" ");
    System.out.println();
}     

public static void main(String a[])
{
    Heap yay = new Heap();

    yay.add(45);
    yay.add(13);
    yay.add(17);
    yay.add(77);
    yay.add(55);
    yay.add(16);
    yay.add(22);
    yay.add(44);
    yay.add(46);
    yay.add(1);
    yay.add(12);
    yay.add(23);

    yay.remove();
    yay.remove();
    System.out.println(yay.peekMax());

    yay.print();
}
}
```

Comment: i still dont understand the problem!

Comment: The remove method changes some numbers to 13 instead of the actual number. Instead of printing: 55,46,23,44,45,22,17,13,16,1,12
It prints: 55 46 23 13 45 22 17 13 16 1 12

Comment: or maybe it doesn't change the number, your heapify method moves the number 13 after deleting the maximum?

Comment: Maybe, I'm not sure. I need some guidance of what to change

Comment: what i intended to say was that 13 might be in the right place if you remove the max! because the tree should heapify itself!

Comment: The last 13 is in the right place but there is an added one where 44 should be